# sending post data after jQuery Validation not working

Tags: php, jquery, post

So I am creating a small online quiz application with **jQuery** and **PHP**...

The jquery part of it is when I click submit it "Validates" the answers and highlights the answer they chose and tells them if they got it right or wrong...the php part of it tallies up there score and if they got 4/5 right it sends an email to an admin to send them a free gift, if they get less then 4 correct they have the option to take it again...

my problem is sending the post data after the jquery validation, it is simply not working... here is snippet example I have tried...

```
quiz.submit(function () {
    if (validateQues1() & validateQues2() & validateQues3() & validateQues4() & validateQues5() & validateQues6()) {
        $.post('includes/validation.php');
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

And validateQues1 looks like this:

```
function validateQues1() {
    var selectedAnswer = $('input[name=q1]:checked', '#quiz').val();
    if (selectedAnswer == 'cartilage') {
        answer1.addClass("correctAnswer");
        $("#ques1 :radio:checked").before("Correct!");
    } else {
        $("#ques1 :radio:checked").parent().addClass("wrongAnswer");
        $("#ques1 :radio:checked").before("Incorrect!");
    }
}
```

thanks for any help in advance, it is greatly appreciated!
~skv

Comment: What does exactly "not working" mean?

Comment: sorry, none of the post data is getting sent to the php script...so if i i write echo $_POST['answer1']; i will get nothing, i know my code on the php side is correct because when i disable the .submit() function in jquery and just run the php it works fine..thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using bit OR rather than logical OR.

```
quiz.submit(function () {
    if (validateQues1() && validateQues2() && validateQues3() && validateQues4() && validateQues5() && validateQues6()) {
        $.post('includes/validation.php');
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

### UPDATE

Your `ValidateQues` function must have a return boolean value, like this:

```
function validateQues1() {
    var selectedAnswer = $('input[name=q1]:checked', '#quiz').val();
    if (selectedAnswer == 'cartilage') {
        answer1.addClass("correctAnswer");
        $("#ques1 :radio:checked").before("Correct!");
        return true;
    } else {
        $("#ques1 :radio:checked").parent().addClass("wrongAnswer");
        $("#ques1 :radio:checked").before("Incorrect!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

You MUST update all your `validateQues` function to return `true`/`false`.

Comment: Please check these returns `validateQues1()`,  `validateQues2()`,  `validateQues3()`,  `validateQues4()`,  `validateQues5()`,  `validateQues6()` `true`/`false` (boolean)

Comment: they look like this                                                  `function validateQues1() {
 var selectedAnswer = $('input[name=q1]:checked', '#quiz').val();
 
 if(selectedAnswer == 'cartilage') {
  answer1.addClass("correctAnswer");
  $("#ques1 :radio:checked").before("Correct!");
 } else {
  $("#ques1 :radio:checked").parent().addClass("wrongAnswer");
  $("#ques1 :radio:checked").before("Incorrect!");
 }
}`         sorry for the formatting

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as "Accepted" by clicking on the tick sign to make others follow the right answer. Thanks

Comment: thanks, i originally had it that way but i noticed my app kept breaking...so i took it out and it worked perfectly...the real problem here is that this is really my first time working with jquery to manipulate the dom...i have been trying to find some examples to work with but nothing that really works, i appreciate your help!

Comment: Please try again - I don't see anything that would break because of returning boolean, rather you need it to perform your AJAX request

Comment: yeah i think my workflow is just a little messed up...i think i need to spend sometime and rethink this....thans for your help though!

Comment: so i have some new developments, i almost have it working properly, the only problem i am having now is that the DOM elements I want to change only change for a split second when the submit button is hit and are not permanent how would I make so they are permanent changes? thanks!